# Identify rows containing a link in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following data:

```
10/24/16    
10/24/16    https://www.example1.com/
10/24/16    http://www.example2.com/
10/24/16    
10/24/16    http://www.example3.com/
10/24/16    http://www.example4.com/
10/24/16    http://www.example5.com/
```

Note that some of the links begin http: and some begin https:.

I would like to input a `1` in every row with a link, and `2` in every row not containing a link. So the result would be:

```
2   10/24/16    
1   10/24/16    https://www.example1.com/
1   10/24/16    http://www.example2.com/
2   10/24/16    
1   10/24/16    http://www.example3.com/
1   10/24/16    http://www.example4.com/
1   10/24/16    http://www.example5.com/
```

Is there a way to do this in Excel?

Comment: Do the cells in the second column contain only a link or are empty (no other possibilities)?  If that's the case, you can just test for a blank cell.  So if the 1st column is col A and the data column is col C, you could put this in A1: =IF(ISBLANK(C1),2,1).

Comment: Hey Fixer1234, looks good. I'll accept as answer if you want to post it. Please upvote the question as well. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful feedback. I agree on all points and will show what I've tried in the future. Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indicated that the last column contains either a link or is blank.  So rather than test for a link, it's simpler to test for a blank.

So if the first column is column A and the data column is column C, you could put this in A1:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C1),2,1)
```